# Extract items from string

Tags: swift, string, split

My JSON data returns a string which I'm having a trouble to deal with right now. It has a key like this

```
"description": "<img src=\"http://www.testing.com/images/flowerOne.jpg\"><p>Erie, Pa., Aug 15, 2018 / 04:59 pm (<a href=\"http://www.testing.com\" target=\"_self\">CNA</a>).- Teachers in (name of town or district) and in communities across the nation will be in the spotlight on National Teacher Day..."
```

but I can't display the exact format like that in my app. I only need the image url

```
http://www.testing.com/images/flowerOne.jpg
```

and the actual content

```
Teachers in (name of town or district) and in communities across the nation will be in the spotlight on National Teacher Day...
```

Can anyone please help me in this case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ios+parse+html

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/2899-how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Comment: @matt I appreciate the link but I'm asking swift question not Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

You can using [**Swift Soup**](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) for parse your response's html string

For example, your json

```
"description": "<img src=\"http://www.testing.com/images/flowerOne.jpg\"><p>Erie, Pa., Aug 15, 2018 / 04:59 pm (<a href=\"http://www.testing.com\" target=\"_self\">CNA</a>).- Teachers in (name of town or district) and in communities across the nation will be in the spotlight on National Teacher Day..."
```

You must get the html string first

```
let htmlString = json["description"]
```

Then, parse your `htmlString` to find the image url

```
do {
    let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlString)
    if let imageLink = try doc.select("img").first()?.attr("src") {
        print("Your image url is ", imageLink)
    } else {
        print("Try break the html your self")
    }
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

and don't forget to import the SwiftSoup

```
import SwiftSoup
```